# Is this the solution to this initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this:

$x'=kx^2$ when $x(0)=0$

I'm supposed to solve it by inspection and the only answer I can come up with is $x=0$.

However, the question that follows in the textbook I'm working with suggests that there are other solutions that depend very much on $k$.  I don't understand how though since, in any case, with the solution

$x(t)=\frac{1}{C-kt}$

I'd end up with $0=\frac{1}{C}$

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you miss nothing. The solution is unique, since $k\,x^2$ is localy Lipschitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Julián Aguirre said, the solution of this initial-value problem is unique. (There's a chance you haven't encountered the relevant theorem yet, in which case of course you aren't expected to use it.)

It is correct that for other initial conditions  ($x(0)=x_0$ with $x_0\ne0$) the solution  is of the form $x(t)=1/(C-kt)$. Since $C=1/x_0$ here, this solution can be rewritten as 
$$x(t) = \frac{x_0}{1-kt x_0} \tag{1}$$
The formula (1) has the nice property of being meaningful for every $x_0$. As you can see, the dependency on $k$ is in a part that has $x_0$ as a factor; when $x_0=0$, the dependency on $k$ is gone.